# Easy SQL Group-By question. (I'm new)

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I am new to SQL so hopefully this has an easy answer.

I have a Students table (studentID, name, statusID)  and a StudentsClasses table (studentID, classID).  I've been asked to create a view from the above tables that returns the following columns:

**classID: (group-by)**

count of students in each class AS Students

count of students where statusID = 1 As Actives

count of students where statusID = 2 As Inactives

I can easily group-by the classID colunm and count the number of students, but i dont think the count function can be told to count only certain rows.  As soon as I add where or Having clauses I lose records that I need to be counted in other columns.  Do I need to write a couple of different queries and then join the results of each?

Thanks for any help you can provide!

-David

Comment: Is this SQL or Mysql? And what language are you ussing? Ex: PHP

Comment: @Zuul - MSSQL 2005 (new view), ASP.NET page will utilize the view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is ANSI SQL (should work as long as your SQL implementation is ANSI compatible):

```
SELECT 
 classID,
 COUNT(*) AS "Students",
 SUM(CASE statusID WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Actives",
 SUM(CASE statusID WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Inactives",
FROM StudentsClasses class
INNER JOIN Students stud ON class.studentID = stud.studentID
GROUP BY classID
```

Comment: Nothing particularly TSQL - that's all ANSI

Comment: Cool thx for the clarification, I have only used T-SQL, so just wanted to cover that base in the case I was using something non-standard. (I edited the answer to clarify)

Comment: Darn, this is exactly the answer I came up with.  Too bad I took time out to watch the world cup for a few minutes first.  Good answer!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of counting, why don't you try summing a couple of IIF/CASE statements? That is, using IIF, your query would be:

```
SELECT ClassId, COUNT(*) AS students,
       SUM(IIF(StatusId = 1, 1, 0)) as Actives,
       SUM(IIF(StatusId = 2, 1, 0)) as Inactives
FROM StudentsClasses
INNER JOIN Students ON StudentsClasses.StudentID = Students.StudentID
GROUP BY ClassId
```

Comment: @William Todd Salzman - Not a whole lot else to say other than: "Wow, sorry I answered what the OP was having trouble with but didn't happen to spoonfeed the entire query. I'm pretty sure the OP knows how to join his tables together; he was asking specifically about how to get the `Actives` and `Inactives` count. Oh, and I'm also a bit surprised you didn't -1 @Brendan Long's answer below, which uses the table `students` where it should be using `studentsclasses`, but whatever."

Answer (score 0):

A statement like this will give you a row for each class with a class ID and the number of students in it.

```
SELECT classID, COUNT(*) AS studentsInClass
    FROM students
    WHERE classID
    IN (SELECT DISTINCT classID FROM students)
    GROUP BY classID
```

The `WHERE x IN (...)` thing is something I just learned.

I'm not really sure about the other part. Do you want this all in one table? You could `UNION` it in, but it would be messy since the data isn't the same.